# Error al bajar el proyecto de github Laravel Lumen

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4, lumen

pues eso al bajar el proyecto de github de lumen ago un composer install y me sale esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y en el archivo git ignore no pongo nada para que se suba todo

Comment: Corrige tu título es confuso, al subir o bajar una copia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solución 1** Saludos si lo que quieres es instalar una copia de Lumen nueva, mejor haz

```
composer global require "laravel/lumen-installer"
```

Y al final

```
lumen new app
```

Y dentro de la carpeta del nuevo proyecto creado

```
composer install
```

**Solución 2** Si te sigue dando error, prueba lo siguiente:

crea una carpeta en tu directorio razíz llamada datase

en tu proyecto borra el composer.lock ese archivo esta en la raíz del proyecto y ejecuta el siguiente comando:

```
composer update
```

Comment: el composer.lock que significa? que contiene ese archivo

Comment: `composer.json` contiene las dependencias del proyecto ( que librería y versión mínima ) `composer.lock` contiene las versiones actualmente instaladas (por install o update), si hay un `.lock`, `composer install` busca esas versiones específicas ( que pueden variar con un `composer update` y no ser totalmente compatibles )